# Dynamic fetch assoc depending on the size

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, resize, fetch

I have a question about making a fetch_assoc more of a dynamic.

```
$i = 0;
echo "<tr>";
while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $i++;
    echo "<td>". $row["stuff"] ."</td>";
    if($i == 3) {
        echo "</tr><tr>";     
        $i = 0;
    }
}
echo "</tr>";
```

I use this way to fetch data from the database and display them on the screen. But this way
is not really good because it will always show 3 td's per tr.

**The question is:** how can I make the fetch_assoc dynamic? Like it depends on the user's screen
size? If the user has a FHD 1080p screen he'll see more td's and if the user has a lower screen 
the fetch_assoc will change.

Comment: Ignoring that there are errors in your code sample, the better way imo of doing this is with CSS and media queries. The page HTML will stay the same, but layout and options shown can vary depending on screen size very easily.

Comment: You should use the modulus operator, or reset the `$i` in the conditional as is `$i` will only equal 3 once. However as @JonStirling has said it would be best to just output the data and have CSS take over, that is its purpose, styling.

Comment: Thank you @JonStirling I edited my sample. Do you have a useful link to that? Thank you

Comment: @ElomarAdam The sample still has errors :P. I don't have a useful link, but just google'ing for "css media queries" should bring up plenty of resources.

Comment: @JonStirling What is the error in the sample?

Comment: This is definitely front-end: CSS/JS related issue.